# Distribution , mean and variance of random variable

Tags: probability

A secretery introduces $9$ adressed letters into $9$ envelops. $X$ represents the number of letters in the correct envelope.

What's $\operatorname{var}(X)$ and expected value? I'm assuming it should be a Poisson distribution?..I'm new to this chapter and I'm still trying to understand how this problems go

Comment: X seems to be a True or False quantity, not a number.  Clarify.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what to clarify,all I know from this problem is that its" a random variable and it represents the number of letters that are in the right envelope".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a Poisson distribution, possion variable can take arbitarily large positive number but the maximum value of $X$ is $9$.

Hint:

Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^9 X_i$ where $X_i$ takes value $1$ if the $i$-th envelop has the right letter and $0$ otherwise.

Then we have $$X^2=\sum_{i=1}^9 X_i^2+\sum_{i \neq j} X_iX_j$$

and use linearity of expectation.

Comment: Thank you,I think I got it partially but I want to look more into this kind of problems,do you by any chance know a site where I could see more solved problems like this?

Comment: this is a famous problem known as old hat problem. you might like to read on derangement and  indicator variables.

Comment: I looked a bit into this problem and just to make sure would E (x) be equal to 1/9?

Comment: not really. start by computing $E(X_i)$ first.

Comment: Question, then $E[X_iX_j]=1/9$ and but what is $\sum_{i\neq j} E[X_iX_j] $ is it $1$?

Comment: Guide: how many ways are there to pick $(i,j)$ where $i$ and $j$ are distinct and $1 \le i, j \le n$? you might like to try with smaller $n$ first? Give it a try, write back if you are stuck.